# How Does SEQUENCE Object Work in Sql Loader

Tags: sql, sequence, sql-loader

I can not find proper documentation of SQEUENCE object used in SQL Loader. Can someone please refer to me to a proper use of SEQUENCE object. How does it get its value. where does it persist etc.

How SEQUENCE (MAX, 1) in SQL LOADER is different from My_Seq.nextval in oracle client ?

Answer (score 0):

Direct load does not allow the `My_Seq.nextval` entity, however, as you've indicated, the SEQUENCE(max,1) construct can be used. The documentation is found in the utilities reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SUTIL/toc.htm

Comment: I still do not get proper comparative analysis with respect to performance/ thread-safety etc. In-case I am not using direct loads, which one is preferable over other and why? What is the core implementation difference between the two ?